# Multiple logback.xml

Tags: logback, slf4j

I have created a jar file, example.jar, to be consumed by various project at my work place. The jar does have SLF4J for logging, backed by Logback.

However during build , I have excluded logback.xml with assumption that actual application will be having its own logback.xml.

Now , even though actual application does have its logback.xml, logger messages from example.jar are missing .

Could you please guide how to handles multiple logback in above mentioned scenario.

Comment: forgot to mention , example.jar is being consumed by play framework web services.

Answer (score 0):

In Play Application , I have added following lines in conf/logback.xml file.

You may disable logging by making level="OFF"